# String of text always appears after cursor in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

A string of text is constantly following the cursor in vscode, I don't know why it's there but, I assume I accidentally pressed a magic combination of keys to save the string. It looks like a comment I made a while ago.[image]

Comment: disable your extension one by one until it disappears

Comment: @rioV8 That seemed to work, it was a problem with "Kite AutoComplete", didn't even realize it was installed. Thanks

Comment: In the Command Palette using `Extension Bisect` is the best way to check which extension is causing a problem - if you have a fair number of extensions installed.